# n x n matrix has the same eigenvalues as its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to prove that a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues.

I can prove that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same entries on the diagonal, but I am not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the $n \times n$ matrix $A$ iff $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$.

Remember that the determinant of a matrix is equal to the determinant of its transpose.  Thus if $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ then $\det([A-\lambda I]^T)=0$.  But $[A-\lambda I]^T = A^T-\lambda I^T = A^T - \lambda I$.  Therefore $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0 \implies \det(A^T - \lambda I) =0$.  Thus $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: I follow you up until the last sentence. I'm not sure how you went from det(A^T - lambdaI) = 0 to them both having the same eigenvalues.

Comment: The equation $\det(A^T- \lambda I) = 0$ implies that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$.  But that eigenvalue was arbitrary (as in this same argument will work for *any* of $A$'s eigenvalues), so*all* of $A$'s eigenvalues are also eigenvalues of $A^T$.  Then to see that $A$ also has all of $A^T$'s eigenvalues, just realize that $(A^T)^T=A$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. If $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$ is the same as $\det(A^T - \lambda I) = 0$  then they both have the same solution for the $\lambda$s?

Comment: $\det(B-aI)=0$ is the *definition* of $a$ being an eigenvalue of the matrix $B$.  So in your problem, we proved that $\det(A-\lambda I)=0 \implies \det(A^T -\lambda I)=0$, therefore we proved that $\lambda$ being an eigenvalue of $A$ implies $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$.  And by a very similar argument, you can prove that $\lambda$ being an eigenvalue of $A^T$ implies it is an eigenvalue of $A$.  So the set of all eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^T$ are exactly the same.

Comment: okay, I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: They will have the same eigenvalues if they have the same characteristic polynomial. (which can be shown that they do have the same easily)